# Amazon S3 multipart upload often fails

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I'm trying to upload a **32GB** file to a S3 bucket using the s3cmd CLI. It's doing a multipart upload and often fails. I'm doing this from a server which has a 1000mbps bandwidth to play with. But the upload still is VERY slow. Is there something I can do to speed this up?

On the other hand, the file is on the HDFS on the server I mentioned. Is there a way to reference the Amazon Elastic Map Reduce job to pick it up from this HDFS? It's still an upload but the job is getting executed as well. So the overall process is much quicker.

Comment: see if the following issue helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774808/s3cmd-failed-too-many-times

Answer (score 0):

First I'll admit that I've never used the Multipart feature of s3cmd, so I can't speak to that. However, I have used [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) in the past to upload large (10-15GB files) to S3 with a good deal of success. In fact, it became such a common task for me that I wrote a [little utility](https://github.com/mumrah/s3-multipart) to make it easier.

As for your HDFS question, you can always reference an HDFS path with a fully qualified URI, e.g., hdfs://{namenode}:{port}/path/to/files. This assumes your EMR cluster can access this external HDFS cluster (might have to play with security group settings)