# Uploading a huge file from ec2 to s3 fails

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload 160 Gb file from ec2 to s3 using

```
s3cmd put --continue-put FILE s3://bucket/FILE
```

but every time uploading interrupts with the message:

```
FILE -> s3://bucket/FILE [part 10001 of 10538, 15MB] 8192 of 15728640 0% in 1s 6.01 kB/s  failed

ERROR: Upload of 'FILE' part 10001 failed. Aborting multipart upload.
ERROR: Upload of 'FILE' failed too many times. Skipping that file.
```

The target bucket does exist.

What is the issue's reason?

Are there any other ways to upload the file?

Thanks.

Comment: Lots of possible solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774808/s3cmd-failed-too-many-times

Comment: thank you! One of it resolved my problem, but what caused the issue?

Comment: the solution for this particular case:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/22107084/3189744

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have up to 10000 upload parts per object, so it fails on part 10001. Using larger parts may solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

"huge"---is it 10s or 100s of GBs? s3 limits the object size to 5GB and uploading may fail if it exceeds the size limitation.

Comment: the file has 160 GB size.
I had no problems with uploading up to 80 GB files

Comment: Ahh... My outdated info about S3.. They support up to 5TB now: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/12/amazon-s3-object-size-limit.html